# splash screen in framework 7 when exported app with phonegap

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, html-framework-7, phonegap

I want to change my splash screen in my app when I exported it with PhoneGap.
I read in the documentation about each size, but I'm not sure if I need to do it manually. I mean to save each logo in each format with Photoshop.
So I want to know how to do that?

When I used in Ionic, I know I just have to run a command and it saves it when I exported the app in each size.
I already tried to save each photo manually but I'm not sure if this is what I need to export.
These are the sizes for example:

```
     <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_640x960.png" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_ldpi.png"        gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_mdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_hdpi.png"        gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_xhdpi.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_640x960.png"               gap:platform="blackberry" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_mdpi.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_640x960.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_640x1136.png"   gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_768x1024.png"             gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_1024x768.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
  <gap:splash src="application_icons/SAMSSplash_640x960.png"        gap:platform="winphone" />
```

How can I do that here?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this web site](http://pgicons.abiro.com/) is very simple and easy to use.
Or [this one](http://apetools.webprofusion.com/tools/imagegorilla) a little more complete.

Answer (score 0):

use this website to generate icons https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ it has different type of icon, for android assets select "Launcher icon"

Extract the zip file you dowload after creating your asset on the link and  copy the `"res/"` folder to your cordova app root.

Open your config and paste:

```
<icon density="ldpi" src="res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
```

in your config, inside tag:

```
    <platform name="android">
     .......
     </platform>
```